# iOS - Rename the BundleId and project name through script file

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I want to rename the bundle Id, project name and certificate through the script

But this script file **should not be in project directory**, it can be on some server

My project contains both objective c and swift files

and XCODE version is 10.1

Comment: So you are asking how to manipulate a file in a different directory to the script file?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of running a ruby script to modify the info.plist

Comment: And what's the actual issue?  Your question seems like an interview question where you want someone else to do your work for you, as you are unable.